# how to get the child XElements with no prefix inside an XElement with prefix

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have been playing with XML in VB.net which is rather different from the way you do it in C#,
it seams more natural to traverse nodes. Then, you come across namespaces.

First of all, I used the imports like:

```
Imports <xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/myDataSet.xsd">
Imports <xmlns="http://tempuri.org/MyDataSet.xsd">
Imports <xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
Imports <xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
Imports <xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop">
```

and then I tried to access the TableAdapter nodes like this:

```
  Dim doc As XDocument

  Dim tableAdapters As XElement

  doc = XDocument.Load(file.FullName)

 tableAdapters = (From item As XElement In doc.<xs:schema>.
                                               <xs:annotation>.
                                               <xs:appinfo>.
                                               <DataSource>. 
                                               <Tables>.
                                               <TableAdapter>
                                               Select item).FirstOrDefault()
```

[Ignore the line breaks, I did it only for readability]

I can get the nodes correctly until xs:appinfo, after that, any node I attempt to retrieve is null

what am I doing wrong?

Below is the normal xml structure of a dataset:

[image: XML structure of a normal dataset]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, I already found the problem. The DataSource node was not using a prefix namespace but it was actually **using a namespace AS AN ATTRIBUTE** after all. You can see that in the image (as xmlns).

So to solve it, you do like this:

add another imports with the namespace of xmlns found as attribute  in the node:

```
Imports <xmlns:datasource="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
```

then retrieve like this:

```
        tableAdapters = (From item As XElement In doc.<xs:schema>.
                                                     <xs:annotation>.
                                                     <xs:appinfo>.
                                                      <datasource:DataSource>.
                                                    <datasource:Tables>.
                                                    <datasource:TableAdapter> 
                          Select item).FirstOrDefault()
```